# как посчитать кол-во строк в консоли

Tags: bash, unix

выполнил баш-команду внутри sh скрипта, ее результат - список строк. Как посчитать кол-во этих строк и запихнуть в if в следущей команде в скрипте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для подсчёта количества строк можно использовать `wc`

```
RESULT=$(/path/to/command.sh | wc -l)
if [ $RESULT == 0 ]
then
    echo "=0"
else
    echo "!=0"
fi
```

Comment: /path/to/command.sh это полный путь до скрипта, который выполняется?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov Команда или путь к файлу (относительный или абсолютный) в выводе которой нужно посчитать строки

Comment: Я бы не стал разводить башизмы там, где их легко избежать, а именно *$result = 0*.